# Migrate Meteor MongoDB from one VPS to another?

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to transfer Meteor app or just its MongoDB between different VPS providers.

I tried this - [Best way to migrate data between two linux VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/444270/best-way-to-migrate-data-between-two-linux-vps) and redeployed app to new VPS. I got an empty app so now I'm trying to find a way to move MongoDB too.

Also found this - [Migrating from Meteor Hosting (.meteor.com) to my own VPS](https://medium.com/@joe.innes/migrating-from-meteor-hosting-meteor-com-to-my-own-vps-a86edf9b772d#.31e7xfi7l) but don't know how to apply this to a production app on Digital Ocean.

Looking for any advice on this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just issue the `mongodump` command on the first VPS, then copy the files it creates to the other VPS, then run the `mongorestore` command.